# Unique continuation for integral operator

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, integral-operators

I accidentally met such question. Let's start from easy ones.

Let $\Omega$ be an open convex domain in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $u(x)$ satisfies that
$$u(x) = \int_{\partial\Omega} \nabla_y G(|x-y|)\cdot n_y f(y) d\sigma(y)$$
with
$$G(r) = -\int_{r}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\rho} d\rho$$
then $u(x)$ has the weak unique continuation property (wucp) since $\Delta u = 0$ inside $\Omega$.

So I wonder if there is a general theory to deal with the unique continuation for integral operators. For example, if we change the integral with
$$u(x) = \int_{\partial\Omega} \nabla_y H(|x-y|)\cdot n_y f(y) d\sigma(y)$$
where
$$H(r) = -\int_{r}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\rho}}{\rho} d\rho$$
do we still have the wucp? Now $u$ no longer satisfies a LOCAL PDE anymore.

Any advice or reference will be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: For disk, this can be proved with analytic continuation.

Comment: just update, proved.